# Botcopy Error 400 Webhook call failed with connection to Dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am having an error with Botcopy, I created an agent and connected it to my Dialogflow to test it, but it is getting this error out of nowhere.

It's just a simple test, no hard configuration, so I am not sure.

[image]

Comment: Can you try this [link](https://bobcares.com/blog/webhook-error-400) hopeful it will help you ?